# SQL - Query from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a project, I had to write two tables and do a query on them. I have written the tables but need some guidance with the query part.

Here is the first table.

```
CREATE TABLE Country
(Name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Code VARCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT CountryKey PRIMARY KEY,
Capital VARCHAR(35),
Province VARCHAR(35),
Area NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CountryArea
    CHECK (Area >= 0),
Population NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CountryPop
    CHECK (Population >= 0));
```

Here is second table.

```
CREATE TABLE City
(Name VARCHAR(35),
Country VARCHAR(4),
Province VARCHAR(35),
Population NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CityPop
    CHECK (Population >= 0),
Longitude NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CityLon
    CHECK ((Longitude >= -180) AND (Longitude <= 180)) ,
Latitude NUMERIC CONSTRAINT CityLat
    CHECK ((Latitude >= -90) AND (Latitude <= 90)) ,
CONSTRAINT CityKey PRIMARY KEY (Name, Country, Province));
```

My query must do the following:

```
Return the min, max, and average latitude of all cities for all the countries in the table. 
And should be ordered by continent first and country second.
```

This is in PostgreSQL.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't disclose the RDBMS in your question: is it MySQL *or* PostgreSQL?

However, this should work in both:

```
SELECT 
      continent -- not quite sure what this refers to
    , ctr.Code AS country_code
    , avg(city.latitude) AS avg_population
    , min(city.latitude) AS min_population
    , max(city.latitude) AS max_population
FROM
    country ctr
    JOIN city ON ctr.Code = city.Country
GROUP BY 
      continent
    , ctr.Code
ORDER BY 
      continent
    , ctr.Code
;
```

The `GROUP BY` clause makes the computed values refer to the ctr.Code.

Comment: Sorry. Its in postgres and it is finding avg, min, and max latitude.

thank you for this!